# Class not appending when click using ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a scenario where when click i am changing the border color from black to red by append a class to a div using ng-class.

But when i click a button the modal is getting triggered but the class is not getting appended.

```
<div ng-class="{'addBorder':clicked}" class="beforeClicked">
<button ng-click="clickToOpen()">My Modal</button>
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope, ngDialog) {
$scope.clicked=false;
$scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        $scope.clicked=true;
    ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId' });
};
```

}

```
.addBorder{
  border:1px solid red;

}
.beforeClicked{
 width:100px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/693/)

Here the div is already in black border when click on button i am making the flag true which should add class `addBorder` to the div which appends red color border.

But it isn't happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `beforeClicked` border properties are overriding the border of `.addBorder`.

Just interchange the order of your css styles for `.addBorder` to have more preference.

```
.beforeClicked {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

.addBorder {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nashcheez/mb6o4yd1/700/

Answer (score 0):

just make the style `!important`

```
.addBorder{
  border:1px solid red !important;      
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/699/)

Answer (score 0):

Update your css like below

```
.beforeClicked{
 width:100px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid black
}

.addBorder{
  border:1px solid red;

}
```

add border class after before clicked class.